# Disable numerical sorting in Egit for Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, egit

I'm having an issue with Egit plugin for eclipse. Within the git repository view, all the files are sorted numerical instead of by name. I already disabled numerical sorting within Windows but this did not change a thing within eclipse.

Is there a way to change the sorting options for the egit plugin so I can sort it by name?

Printscreens of the current and how I want it to be:

[GIT Repository view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aXD8J.jpg)

[how I want it to be](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YR9LT.jpg)

Comment: Sort what, where?

Comment: Within the GIT repository view, the files are sorted numerical. I have uploaded 2 printscreens to the post. with the current view and how I want it to be.

Comment: AFAIK lexicographic order cannot be disabled, neither in your system explorer nor in Eclipse. By the way, your Eclipse looks pretty outdated. Please upgrade.

Comment: Thanks for the information, The version of eclipse is use is provided by IBM.(Developer for zOS). This is the latest version IBM provides.